# float гораздо быстрее, чем double

Tags: c++, оптимизация, float, double, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Есть многократное вычисление формулы `y = f(x, exp(y))`, в которой есть с пяток умножений, делений и одно вычисление экспоненты

При работе с типом float скорость на 1 - 2 порядка (!!!) быстрее, чем с double, но иногда все таки нужна именно двойная точность (при нестабильном поведении функции около некоторых критических точек)

Такой вопрос - с чем связано такое проседание в скорости с арифметикой двойной точности и можно ли это как-то побороть силами ЦП (без каких-то расчётов на GPU)?

Или это особенность архитектуры процессора и ничего не сделать?

Comment: я думаю это особенность реализации типов, плюс оптимизация, а архитектура процессора непричем. В обеих случаях адреса попадуд в хэш одинакового порядка.  P.S.  я  не уверен, просто рассуждаю чисто по своей логике

Comment: я бы мог ожидать двухкратного падения скорости (просто потому что обрабатывается 8 байт, а не 4), но когда скорость в 10 раз падает - становится как-то грустно

посмотрел на то, как дела на видеокартах - там float так же заметно быстрее, но вроде там именно архитектурное ускорение float ибо для графики double в общем-то и не нужны

Comment: ну а функция шаблонная?

Comment: А вы бы не могли привести конкретный код - минимальный компилируемый пример - а то что-то не очень верится в 2 порядка... :( Тут какие-то сторонние факторы, и инетерсно бы посмотреть, что и как.

Comment: А система-то какая? на 64-битной системе арифметический сопроцессор должен double обрабатывать со скоростью float.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 У меня на VC++ 2017 как раз наоборот. В 32-разрядном варианте разницы нет, в 64-разрядном `float` немножечко быстрее... Впрочем, и там, и там используются xmm-регистры. А вот если отключить оптимизацию - то в 64 они становятся одинаковы, а в 32 - быстрее `double`.

Comment: на gpu будет та же история с даблами везде, кроме nvidia quadro

Comment: А как вы тестируете функции? Зависит ли диапазон значений от типа? Нет ли внутри цикла с количеством итераций, зависящим от аргументов? И вообще, они хотя бы одинаковые значения возвращают? Чисто технически, большая разница в производительности должна быть только в случае, если у вас 32-х разрядный АЛУ, на котором реализуется 64-разрядная арифметика, что и проявляется на большинстве видеокарт. Если для double используется 64-разрядный АЛУ, разница не должна быть больше, чем в два раза (за счет конвейризации, если только вы не умудрились реализовать абсолютно неконвейризируемую функцию)

Comment: Тут есть зависимость от компилятора и процессора, если можно реализовать поддержку AVX512 то есть пути оптимизации, например ассемблерными вставками.

Comment: Разницу на порядок можно объяснить только тем, что 4-х байтные float операнды все попадают в кэш, а вот 8-ми байтным double его не хватает. Если речь о матрицах, то транспонирование одной из них может решить проблему. Впрочем, без детального рассмотрения алгоритма, ничего конкретного посоветовать не удастся.

Comment: Нужно смотреть ассемблер и количество данных. Проверять в профайлере. Причины могут быть разными.